# Xcode Buttons: Some work, some do not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, ibaction

I am attempting to design an app for my senior project, and am thus fairly new to iOS coding. I have created a .xib view controller, and added a number of buttons to it, over top of some card images. There is one large button over the other player's hand, and sever smaller ones over each of the player's own cards.

I have added UIAlertControllers to each button, intending the pop-ups to allow the player to play or discard their own cards, or send some information about the other player's.

The Alert pops up fine for the other player's button, but the ones for the bottom cards do absolutely nothing. I have checked that they are all connected to the IBActions, and the code is nearly identical to the button that IS working. Any ideas?

This is all contained within `gameViewController.m:` `btnTop` correctly performs its action, while `btnBottom1` - `btnBottom5` do nothing.

```
- (IBAction)btnTop:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Top Button Pressed. Displaying AlertView.");
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Give Information" message:@"Would you like to give information about color or number?" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *actionColor = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Color" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                        handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                  {
                                      [self giveColorInfo];
                                  }];
    UIAlertAction *actionNumber = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Number" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
    UIAlertAction *actionCancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
    [alertController addAction:actionColor];
    [alertController addAction:actionNumber];
    [alertController addAction:actionCancel];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (IBAction)btnBottom1:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Bottom 1 Button Pressed. Displaying AlertController.");
    UIAlertController *alertController2 = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Play or Discard Card 1" message:@"Would you like to play or discard?" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *actionPlay = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Play" 
                                                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                       handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                             {
                                 [self playCard:1];
                             }];

    UIAlertAction *actionDiscard = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Discard" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
    UIAlertAction *actionCancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
    [alertController2 addAction:actionPlay];
    [alertController2 addAction:actionDiscard];
    [alertController2 addAction:actionCancel];
    [self presentViewController:alertController2 animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)btnBottom2:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Bottom 2 Button Pressed. Displaying AlertView.");
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Play or Discard Card 2" message:@"Would you like to play or discard?" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *actionPlay = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Play" 
                                                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                       handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                             {
                                 [self playCard:2];
                             }];
    UIAlertAction *actionDiscard = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Discard" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
    UIAlertAction *actionCancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
    [alertController addAction:actionPlay];
    [alertController addAction:actionDiscard];
    [alertController addAction:actionCancel];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)btnBottom3:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Bottom 3 Button Pressed. Displaying AlertView.");
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Play or Discard Card 3" message:@"Would you like to play or discard?" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *actionPlay = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Play"  
                                                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                       handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                             {
                                 [self playCard:3];
                             }];
    UIAlertAction *actionDiscard = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Discard" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
    UIAlertAction *actionCancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
    [alertController addAction:actionPlay];
    [alertController addAction:actionDiscard];
    [alertController addAction:actionCancel];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)btnBottom4:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Bottom 4 Button Pressed. Displaying AlertView.");
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Play or Discard Card 4" message:@"Would you like to play or discard?" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *actionPlay = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Play"  
                                                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                       handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                             {
                                 [self playCard:4];
                             }];
    UIAlertAction *actionDiscard = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Discard" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
    UIAlertAction *actionCancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
    [alertController addAction:actionPlay];
    [alertController addAction:actionDiscard];
    [alertController addAction:actionCancel];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)btnBottom5:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Bottom 5 Button Pressed. Displaying AlertView.");
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Play or Discard Card 5" message:@"Would you like to play or discard?" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *actionPlay = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Play"  
                                                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                       handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                             {
                                 [self playCard:5];
                             }];
    UIAlertAction *actionDiscard = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Discard" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
    UIAlertAction *actionCancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
    [alertController addAction:actionPlay];
    [alertController addAction:actionDiscard];
    [alertController addAction:actionCancel];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Too much code. Just comment out or temporarily delete all the code in all the methods that don't work and write simple NSLog statements in each. If on button tap the console does not show your log output, your set up (IBAction connection in xib/storyboard) is wrong. And if the log messages do show up for each method, then the code in that method fails. In that case, add multiple logs to debug what should happen at every logical step in the code. Ater you can pin point the problem and cant fix it, edit your question with only the relevant code.

Comment: If the buttons on touch produce no console output from your NSLog, then either the IBAction is not wired up properly or you set the buttons to not be enabled. Check they are enabled.

Comment: Thanks. I commented it all out and it does not perform the NSLog statements. The buttons each have the Touch Up Inside connection to File's Owner btnBottm1, etc.. In their properties, they look identical to the btnTop which is working...

Comment: They are also each enabled.

Comment: Try deleting the app on the device/simulator and then rerun in case it has got itself in a mess.

Comment: I am at a loss. I deleted and recreated them, dragged new to the .h, and created new NSLog statements in the .m. They still do nothing, while the other button works normally.

Comment: Any chance you might have a transparent part of another view over the top preventing input? The buttons need to be in front of all other views or contained within the top view to receive input by default. Views at the bottom of the view hierarchy in the explorer are at the front. Try moving the buttons or the view they are in to the bottom.

Comment: Where do you put your buttons in your view controller?? Is there any difference between btnTop and btnBotton where you put your buttons?

Comment: We could always try using an actual debugger and setting some symbolic breakpoints rather than purely relying on `NSLog` outputs.

Comment: There are no transparent items over them. They are the highest things in the view outline. The bottom buttons go at the very bottom of the screen, over top of the card images, and the top button spans the top of the screen, over the other card images.

Comment: I deleted all of the bottom buttons and created one new button over all of the cards, as I did for the top, and it works. This is not ideal, as it adds another step to the process, requiring the user to select which card they wish to play after already tapping on a card.. But it works. I have no clue what was wrong with the others.

Comment: If you [right click](http://i.imgur.com/vP1hs67.png) the buttons, is their touch-up-inside event linked up like [this](http://i.imgur.com/vP1hs67.png)?

Comment: Do you have transparent(invisible) buttons? I assume you would want that if you have them over some cards. I believe your problem comes from the constraints applied to buttons, and the buttons not being where you think when the app runs. Try to set a background color to buttons to see where they are placed when the app runs.

Comment: The buttons were invisible, yes. I have since deleted and recreated them, and they are now working.. Thanks all for your help.